# ASP.NET MVC - base64String to html image

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a collection of base64Strings which need to be viewed as Images on a View.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can do this? I'm completely stumped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this (this is for one image, but you can easily extend it for a list of them).

(*See the header infront of the base64 string* "***data:image/png;base64,***")

```
//Model
public class ImgModel
{
 public string Src { get; set; }
}

//Action
public ActionResult Index(int id = 0)
{
 var img =@"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
 return View(new ImgModel{Src = img});
}

//View
<div id="kk1">
 <img id="myimg1" src="@Model.Src" alt="Red dot">
</div>
```

The sample img data I have used is from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML)

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure what you mean by: var img =@"data:image/png;base64. I understand that after that there is a base64String but, the data:image.png etc doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: you can read more about data uri in the wikipedia link i mentioned; the format is defined as data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64],<data>

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It saves me a lot of time.

Answer (score 5):

ASP.NET MVC has pretty nice solution for these tasks. We will create an action, which will return a stream representing an image, in a form the Web browser knows.
I am sorry for a large string containing base64 image, but that will assure that you can use it out of the box:

```
static string ImageSource = "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";

    public ActionResult Image()
    {
        var arr = Convert.FromBase64String(ImageSource);
        return this.File(arr, "image/png", "image.png");
    }
```

And then call it from your view

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Image")"/>
```

PS: Expecting you are on a Home controller